# Cannot get value using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**Code**

```
if(x.substr(0,4)=='init') {
    output += 'Initialised<br>';        
    var rgx = /^\[typ-$\]/i;
    if (rgx.test(x))output+='Type given<br>';
    else output+='No type: '+x+'<br>';

}
container.append(output);
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm simulating a command-line terminal for a website. One command is `init` which carries the parameter `type`. The parameter is set by typing:

```
 init [typ-Foo]
```

I'm trying to then get the value of the `type` parameter (in this case, `Foo`).

**What's happening**

I'm failing to get the value at all. It's returning `No Type: init [typ-Foo]` which is what the function returns when no value is found. I haven't played about with Regex before so I'm sure that my command is incorrect but I'm unable to make it work!

Comment: Your regular expression is expecting the string to _begin_ with the bracket (because of the `carat`), while your strings clearly begin with "init".

Comment: @RobI - I took out the `^` and still no luck. The string I'm trying to retrieve (or test, for now) is `Foo` which begins with `[typ-` and ends with `]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = /\[typ-([^\]]+)]/.exec(  userInput  );
if (result){
 console.log("type: " + result[1]);
}
else {
 // no type
}
```

If `result` is `null`, then there's no type. If it isn't, the type is in `result[1]`

This regex looks a little complicated because we're using `[` and `]`s in their special, regex meaning and also as literal characters.

Comment: Clean solution - capture and all - though since the original question's solution had the test for "init" I wonder if that would be part of the requirements?  This solution would accept "finalize [typ-Foo]" as valid input.

Comment: Indeed. The code here is intended only to replace the part that gets the type. The rest of the OP's code looks fine as-is.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do the trick.

```
var rgx = /^init\s\[typ\-([^\]]+)\]/;
```

This is what happens.

[image]

From [Regexper.com](https://regexper.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
var rgx = /^init \[typ-(.*)\]$/i;

m = x.match(rgx);

if ( m != null ) {
    output += 'Initialised<br>';
    output+='Type given<br>';
    output+='Argument: ' + m[1]; // note this is the "Foo" value
}
else {
    output+='No type: '+x+'<br>';
}
container.append(output);
```